# Does Spark optimize higher order chained transformations?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the example below, if we create N columns that use `sorted_array`, will Spark sort the original array N times or WholeStageCodegen will optimize it?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

_data = [
   ([1, 10, 12, 2, 4], ),
   ([1, 100, 4, 1, 5], )
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, ['arr_col'])

sorted_array = F.sort_array('arr_col')
cols = [
   F.slice(sorted_array, 1, 1).alias('c1'),
   F.slice(sorted_array, 1, 2).alias('c2'),
   F.slice(sorted_array, 1, 3).alias('c3')
]
df2 = df.select(cols)
df2.explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [
#        slice(sort_array(arr_col#0, true), 1, 1) AS c1#43,
#        slice(sort_array(arr_col#0, true), 1, 2) AS c2#44,
#        slice(sort_array(arr_col#0, true), 1, 3) AS c3#45
#      ]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[arr_col#0]
```